# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name' error

Tags: python

Code:

```
from fpdf import FPDF


class Bill:
    """
    This class Contains data about a bill, such as Total amount and Period
    """

    def __init__(self, amount, period):
        self.amount = amount
        self.period = period


class Flatmate:
    """Create a flatmate who lives in the house and share the bill """

    def __init__(self, name, days_in_house):
        self.name = name
        self.days_in_house = days_in_house

    def pays(self, bill, flatmate_2):
        weight = self.days_in_house / (self.days_in_house + flatmate_2.days_in_house)
        to_pay = bill.amount * weight
        return to_pay

class PdfReport(Flatmate):
    """Creates a pdf which contains data about flatmates such as name, bill, due amount
    and other things"""

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename

    def generate(self, flatmate1, flatmate2, bill):

        # Stylle of the Pdf
        Pdf = FPDF(orientation='P', unit='cm', format='A4')
        Pdf.add_page()

        # Setting of the title

        Pdf.set_font(family='Times', style='B', size=30)
        Pdf.cell(w=0, h=2, txt='Flatmates Bill', border=0, align='C,ln=1)


        #Insert Period of the bill and the value
        Pdf.cell(w=6, h=2, txt='Period, =1,align='C')
        Pdf.cell(w=8, h=2, txt=bill.period, align='C', border=1,ln=1)


        # Insert name  of the flatmate1 and the amount he has to pay...
        Pdf.cell(w=6, h=2, txt=flatmate1.name, border=1, align='C')
        Pdf.cell(w=8, h=2, txt=str(flatmate1.pays(bill, flatmate2)), align='C', border=1, 
      ln=1)
        Pdf.output(self.filename)

    the_bill = Bill(amount=1000, period="september 2021")
    Vivan = Flatmate(name="Vivan", days_in_house=25)
    Ved = Flatmate(name="Ved", days_in_house=20)

    print("Vivan pays: ",Vivan.pays(bill=the_bill, flatmate_2=Ved))
    print("Ved pays:   ", Ved.pays(bill=the_bill, flatmate_2=Vivan))

    Pdfreport = PdfReport(filename= "Flatmate's Bill September.pdf ")
    Pdfreport.generate(flatmate1= "Vivan",flatmate2="Ved",bill=the_bill)
```

OutPut:

```
Pdfreport.generate(flatmate1= "Vivan",flatmate2="Ved",bill=the_bill)
Pdf.cell(w=6, h=2, txt=flatmate1.name, border=1, align='C')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
Vivan pays:  555.5555555555555
Ved pays:    444.4444444444444
```

Help me pls Stuck in this for 2 days now

Answer (score 1):

You aren't passing in the flatmate, just a string

```
Pdfreport.generate(flatmate1= Vivan,flatmate2=Ved,bill=the_bill)
```

note the removal of quotes